# Camera projection askew

Tags: c++, graphics, camera, directx

A slightly strange question, perhaps, but I have been brushing up on my DirectX and I've hit an odd problem. I recently finished my camera class and when I run the application to view a cube, I notice that the object being viewed isn't centered on the screen. I've double-checked the initialization variables and the vertex coordinates of the cube and they all seem to check out. I'm using a left-handed coordinate system, with the camera located at (0, 0, 10) and it's direction being (0, 0, -1). The cube itself is 6.0f wide, high and deep and centered at the origin. With all of these parameters, the edge between the two front facing sides of the cube should align perfectly with the center of the screen.

This is my result:
[image]

My question is not one that requires code to be posted, so I won't bore you with it until it is necessary. I've been poking at the code for some time and haven't found a possible source yet. My question is more of a theoretical one than anything else, to help me try and understand what is causing this. So, what possible causes could their be for this?
In case it is important, I also calculate my own view matrix, but I've double-checked that code and it seems to check out.

Thank you in advance,
Kevin Delval

Comment: It could be one of many things, I don't think people are going to want to play guess-the-bug bingo.

Comment: Actually, it can only be one of a few conceptual things, I'm sure. The math checks out, the matrices are fed into DirectX correctly, so I'm assuming I'm doing something else wrong. The problem is, I can't post all the related code or I'll end up with a massive question. Though, if that is indeed preferable, then I'll edit the post and paste in what code is relevant, and try to keep it brief.

Comment: Is the cube rotated by exactly 45°? It does not seem so. The left top edge has an angle of 25° and the right one has 17°. Make sure that there are no further translations.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I had tested out some rotation code and a single line had slipped in that I didn't remove. However, are there other reasons why something may appear off-center? I had run into things online that spoke of reversing the order in which the view and projection matrices are multiplied, thereby creating an off-center camera. Is there validity to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to rotations, not my matrix math.
Removing the sneaky rotation solved the problem.